# Storing application settings in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, dll, silverlight-3.0, assemblies

I want to be able to change a setting in my silverlight assembly at runtime, i want a bit like a web.config in  a asp.net web site?

what is the best way of doing this?

thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at [IsolatedStorageSettings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings(VS.95).aspx). You have ApplicationSettings (specific to a single application on a site) and SiteSettings (for all applications at a particular domain). Note that in both cases, settings are specific to a user.

A quick example:

```
private void StoreSetting(string key, string value)
{
   IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[key] = value;
}

private string GetSetting(string key)
{
   return IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings[key];
}
```